# Getting a timeline from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, timeline

I have a multidimensional array displayed from two arrays:

```
$years = array(2015, 2016, 2017);
```

And:

```
$content = array('Hello', 'World', 'Good', 'Morning');
```

This is the multidimenional array

Array
(
    [2015] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hello_2015
            [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Botyr.png) => World_2015
            [2] => Good_2015
            [3] => Morning_2015
        )

```
[2016] => Array
    (
        [0] => Hello_2016
        [1] => World_2016
        [2] => Good_2016
        [3] => Morning_2016
    )

[2017] => Array
    (
        [0] => Hello_2017
        [1] => World_2017
        [2] => Good_2017
        [3] => Morning_2017
    )
```

)

Further, I want a timeline from the above output in which first block(2015 one) should come on left side , second block (2016 one) on right side and the third one(2017 one) again on left side of a vertical timeline in PHP. The desciption below shows the output I need. Thank you :)

[image]

Comment: also include your expected output

Comment: What is this timeline supposed to look like? I also don't see any multidimensional arrays anywhere.

Comment: Array
(
    [2015] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hello_2015
            [1] => World_2015
            [2] => Good_2015
            [3] => Morning_2015
        )

    [2016] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hello_2016
            [1] => World_2016
            [2] => Good_2016
            [3] => Morning_2016
        )

    [2017] => Array
        (
            [0] => Hello_2017
            [1] => World_2017
            [2] => Good_2017
            [3] => Morning_2017
        )

)
2015 should be on left side 2016 on right 2017 again on left,verticaltimeline

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to show us what you have already tried, and describe what _specifically_ you are having problems with. This is not a site where you just tell us what you “want”, and someone will make it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this (that will create the multidimensional array)?

```
$years = array(2015, 2016, 2017);

$content = array('Hello', 'World', 'Good', 'Morning');

foreach ($years as $year) {

    foreach( $content as $data ) {

        $timeline[$year][] = $data .'_' . $year ;

    }

}
```

That will produce:

```
array (size=3)
  2015 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'Hello_2015' (length=10)
      1 => string 'World_2015' (length=10)
      2 => string 'Good_2015' (length=9)
      3 => string 'Morning_2015' (length=12)
  2016 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'Hello_2016' (length=10)
      1 => string 'World_2016' (length=10)
      2 => string 'Good_2016' (length=9)
      3 => string 'Morning_2016' (length=12)
 2017 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string 'Hello_2017' (length=10)
      1 => string 'World_2017' (length=10)
      2 => string 'Good_2017' (length=9)
      3 => string 'Morning_2017' (length=12)
```

Comment: Please check timeline on google,,,actually i want it in timeline structure i.e. first block of the output u printed should(2015) be on the left side  , second block(2016) on right side, third on left side again. It should be a vertical timeline as th desired output